# Downloading image data to unity3D using php

Tags: php, unity-game-engine

i am trying to download images from a server, i give the name of the image and if it exists server sends me the data
This is the php part:

```
if ($_POST) 
 {
     if ( isset ($_POST['fileToDownload']) ) 
     {
             $file = $_POST['fileToDownload'];
             echo $file . "\n";
             $path = 'uploads/' . $file;
            if(file_exists($path)){
              $imgEncode = file_get_contents($path, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
              echo $imgEncode;       
            }
            else{
             echo "File does not exist";
            }
     }
 }
```

This is my code in unity:

```
public Texture2D texture ;
static string image_url = "http://localhost/aditya/download.php";

IEnumerator DownloadImage(){

        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("fileToDownload" , file + ".png");

        WWW download = new WWW(image_url, form);

        yield return download;
        // check for errors
        if (download.error == null)
        {
            texture = new Texture2D(64, 64, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
            download.LoadImageIntoTexture(texture);
            Debug.Log(download.text);

            download.Dispose();
            download = null;

        } else {
            Debug.Log("WWW Error: "+ download.error);
        }   

    }
void OnGUI(){

        GUI.Label( new Rect (10, 10, 80, 20), "File name:" );           
        file = GUI.TextField ( new Rect (90, 10, 100, 20), file );    
        if ( GUI.Button ( new Rect (10, 90, 100, 20) , "download image" ) ){ //just a button
            StartCoroutine(DownloadImage());
        }    
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(100, 10, 500, 300), texture, ScaleMode.ScaleToFit, true, 0);

    }
```

the image is showing up as red question mark, i tried changing the TextureFormat to ARGB32 (which unity says is the format for a .png file) but its not working. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove

```
echo $file . "\n";
```

From your php script, it echoes file name before actual image content so Unity can't identify image format and thus can't load image data.

You may also consider using [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) function instead of

```
$imgEncode = file_get_contents($path, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
echo $imgEncode;
```

Comment: k, its working. i was using  `echo $file . "\n"; `  for testing purposes and forgot  to remove it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Unity3D and serving images using PHP one big difference I see that you may be missing here is the Content-Type header. I know in normal web dev in IE you have to send the header for it to work well. Here is my CakePHP code:

```
public function doImage($id=null) {

    $doThumb=(isset($this->request->query['doThumb'])) ? (bool)$this->request->query['doThumb'] : false;
    $doMed=(isset($this->request->query['doMed'])) ? (bool)$this->request->query['doMed'] : false;
    $doLg=(isset($this->request->query['doLg'])) ? (bool)$this->request->query['doLg'] : false;

    $data=null;

    if($id==null) {
        $data = $this->GameDrawing->find('first', array('fields'=>array('MAX(GameDrawing.id) AS maxID','linedata')));
        if($data) {
            $id=$data[0]['maxID'];
        }
    }
    $this->GameDrawing->recursive=-1;
    $data = $this->GameDrawing->read(null, $id);

    header("Content-Type: image/png"); 
    if($data) {

        if($data['GameDrawing']['flagged']) {

            echo file_get_contents(WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . 'ss-web-flagdrawing.png');

        } else {

            //Do Thumbnail
            if($doThumb) {                

                $file = $this->GameDrawing->getThumb($id, 213, 143);

            } else if($doMed) {

                $file = $this->GameDrawing->getMed($id, 841, 566);

            } else if($doLg) {

                $file = $this->GameDrawing->getLg($id, 700, 570);

            } else {

                //Do Normal Image
                $file = $this->GameDrawing->getImage($id);
            }

            if($file) {

                header("Cache-Control: no-cache"); 
                header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
                echo file_get_contents(ROOT . DS . 'ss-upload' . DS . $file);

            } else {
                //show default image
                echo file_get_contents(WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . 'ss-web-nodrawing.png');
            }
        }
    } else {
        //show default image
        echo file_get_contents(WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . 'ss-web-nodrawing.png');
    }
    exit();
}
```

This code is working from the PHP side.

On the Unity3D C# side I have had success using [WWWW.texture](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-texture.html) like this...

```
...

    WWW download = new WWW(image_url, form);

    yield return download;
    // check for errors
    if (download.error == null)
    {
        texture = downloaded.texture;
        download.LoadImageIntoTexture(texture);
        Debug.Log(download.text);

        download.Dispose();
        download = null;

    } else {
        Debug.Log("WWW Error: "+ download.error);
    }

...
```

Hope this helps!